# Check if value contains in List (Similar values)

Tags: kotlin

I have a List of numbers where the numbers could be saved in different ways, with or without the prefix like

"+391112223214, 7251234785, +393911114578, 052264245"

Then i have in input a number which has alway +39 in it or any other country code

at this point i have to check if that number exist in the list

i've tried to use `in` but if the number in list is 1112223214 and the one in input is +391112223214 the match will fail when i would that to be a valid check..

Here is what i've tried:

```
val number = phoneNumber.removeTelPrefix().parseCountryCode() // value +391112223214 or any other in input
val contatti = contattiPrefs.split("#")
if (number in contatti) {
    return response
}
```

So how can i check if the list contains a value almost identical to the one in input but with some "differences" like +39?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly do one of two things:

1. Split and convert to a list of Strings. Normalize the list before checking which is remove the prefixes +39 from any numbers that have and then use the resulting list
2. Split and convert it to a list of Strings. Use an `endsWith` comparison instead of `in` ,

   ```
   contacts.filter{ it.endsWith("1112223214") }
   ```

Comment: will `endsWith` return the value even if it match it? input `+391112223214` and in list the same

Comment: just tried and works as expected even with input which match the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.contains(Regex)`.

```
input.contains("${number}$".toRegex())
```

will give you true if you number is suffix of your input.

Ex:

```
"+393911114578".contains("3911114578$".toRegex())
```

Remember that, `$` at the end means that match the string end with it.

With regex you may add additional control like start with +, length of ...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `any` instead of `contains`, you can pass in a predicate that handles your comparison logic, if you ever need to do anything more complicated that `endsWith` can't handle.

Another option you might want to consider is creating a separate `PhoneNumber` type, and putting comparison logic in there - maybe even override its `equals` method. Phone numbers can get a little screwy, especially if you're letting the user store them however they like (prefix or no prefix, starting *0* optional, spaces allowed etc) so it might be a good idea to encapsulate all that logic in one place.

Plus you can validate them when they're constructed, reformat the input to a standard representation (like stripping spaces) etc, so you end up with guarantees a bare `String` can't give you. Might be too much for what you're doing but it's something to think about!